# Tomcat server port in use

Tags: java

I have updated my Eclipse Oxygen version from 4.7.0 to 4.7.2. After that my Apace tomcat server 8 is not starting up stating the port is already in use.

I have tried changing the port numbers, killing the java task in task manager, shutdown .bat in bin folder. the error remains the same

Comment: Try reload you PC :)

Answer (score 0):

change the port by double click on the server in server console -> Port Number -> change the port number for an other one.